# What is the difference between :to and => in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been noticing that the rails community has been moving towards using the ":" notation for more things. And now recently I received a comment in a code review that this:

```
post 'examples/', to: 'examples#index'
```

was better than this:

```
post "examples/" => "examples#index"
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a difference between these two statements?
2. If so why is one better than the other?
3. Why is the rails community switching to the ":" notation (or are they)?
4. Moving forward with rails 4 and soon 5, are both formats still acceptable?

Comment: the colon is a shorthand for when keys are symbols. Will not have any effect from Rails 4 => 5 - this is a ruby language thing

Comment: Technically the first is identical to `post "examples/" :to => "examples#index"` The `post` method accepts a number of definitions, including a simple hash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In context of Rails routes:

- Is there a difference between these two statements?

There is no difference.

- If so why is one better than the other?

No, it's the same.

- Why is the rails community switching to the ":" notation (or are
  they)?

Just a more readable, `'from' => 'to'` and `'from', to: 'to'`

- Moving forward with rails 4 and soon 5, are both formats still
  acceptable?

Yes.

The `=>` notation it's a hash ruby feature, and related to the `:symbol`. 
You can write symbols by two ways `:key => value` and `key: value`.